# Извлечь данные из БД

Tags: mysql, база-данных

СУБД MySQL
Имеется 2 таблицы:

```
transactions
id|sum|receiver|sender

users
id|nickname
```

receiver и sender содержат ID пользователей из таблицы users

Нужно извлечь данные из transactions чтобы вместо receiver и sender подставились не ID, а nickname

Пробовал с помощью LEFT JOIN там получается извлечь заменив только один из столбцов, при этом неизвестно какой.

Comment: напишите ваш запрос как он есть сейчас

Comment: @ArchDemon SELECT u.nickname FROM transactions as t LEFT JOIN users as u ON t.receiver = u.id

Comment: Не добавляйте код (запрос) в комментарий. Отредактируйте ваш вопрос. Почему в запросе не видно ещё одного LEFT JOIN для получения sender?

Comment: Поскольку надо заменить значения двух независимых полей, нужно две копии таблицы-словаря - своя для каждого расшифровываемого поля.

Comment: @ArchDemon спасибо, добавьте свой ответ на вопрос чтобы отметить его как решение